# Need help vertically centering elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I know there are a lot of questions and answers here on how to vertically center divs, but I've tried far too many of them and none work, and some seem way to complex, so I just need help with someone experienced that knows the simplest solution that just works.

Below is an image of my situation:

[image: Div layout]

The red outer div, inner left green div, and the inner right blue div all have the bootstrap `pull-left` class.

So how do i cleanly make sure that my inner blue div (inside the green div), that is also an image, and both the 'some text' and the yellow div which is a button, be vertically centered like in the image.

Here is the html (edited):

```
<div class="pull-left user-info">
    <div class="pull-left profile-image-wrap">
        <img class="profile-image" src="~/Content/Images/user.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left user-desc">
        <h1>Bok <strong>@Model.Korisnik.Ime</strong>!</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Nova uplata</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.user-info {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.profile-image-wrap {
    display: flex;
}

.profile-image {
  height: 70px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.user-desc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3?

Comment: @MichaelCoker bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the parent and on the vertically centered content, use `flex` with `flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

```css
.user-info {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.profile-image-wrap {
    display: flex;
}

.profile-image {
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.user-desc, .profile-image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="user-info">
  <div class="profile-image-container">
    <img class="pull-left profile-image" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="user-desc">
    <h1>Bok <strong>@Model.Korisnik.Ime</strong>!</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Nova uplata</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much, any idea why it doesn't work for the image if i copy the .user-desc css to .profile-image ?

Comment: Oh wait i probably need to wrap the image into a div

Comment: @m_bale yeah depends on what your other CSS is. But I would recommend wrapping the image in a div - having an `img` as a flex child can be weirdly problematic with other CSS.

Comment: Just tried that and doesn't work :/, the only css I have for the image is margin-right and height

Comment: @m_bale unless my demo is also broken, post all of your code, otherwise all I can do is guess. If my demo is broken for you, tell me what isn't working.

Comment: Hi I edited the question, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @m_bale awesome you bet